# Entity Framework SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I hope anyone can help me.

How do I build up a query like this in Entity Framework in C#.

My SQL query looks like this:

```
select Id, dbo.AccessRight(Id, 5)
from Customers
where Id in (select top 10000 Id 
             from Customers 
             where dbo.AccessRight(Id, 5) > 0)
```

The second select statement should be replaced in code with an list of ids.

Comment: you can do `dbContext.Database.Query<T>(sqlQueryString)` where `T` is the dto that represents an `Id` and `AccessRight` and `sqlQueryString` is the sql you have provided

Answer (score 1):

Your `AccessRight` seems to be a user defined function.

If that is the case, then you are stuck with calling `context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(YourSQL)` as EF doesn't support user defined functions.

UPDATE:
You asked `What if you have the id list?`. Assuming you have an `ids` list.

```
from c in Customer
where ids.Contains(c.Id)
select c
```

However, can't yet run the `dbo.AccessRight(Id, 5)` user defined function to show in your select result.

### You actually can

Forgive my previous lack of knowledge. You can actually call user defined functions with EF.

Inside your Database context, you can do something like this (this code was actually generated by EF EDMX tool although I removed a few things for simplicity):

```
public virtual ObjectResult<usp_GetAppropriatenessQuestionsWithMetadata_Result> usp_GetAppropriatenessQuestionsWithMetadata(Nullable<int> languageId)
    {
        var languageIdParameter = languageId.HasValue ?
            new ObjectParameter("LanguageId", languageId) :
            new ObjectParameter("LanguageId", typeof(int));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<usp_GetAppropriatenessQuestionsWithMetadata_Result>("usp_GetAppropriatenessQuestionsWithMetadata", languageIdParameter);
    }
```

Comment: Yes it is an user defined function.

Comment: True but I guess you might need to change `context.Database.Query<T>(YourSQL)` to `context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(YourSQL)`

Comment: @uteist But could you please tell me, if I have any chance to pass a List of Ids into? So that I can replace the second "select" in the this call with an List of Ids?

Comment: @Marius, the update will probably be closer to what you want.

Comment: Well, I think you could do it in 2 separate queries. First being the _user defined function_ but not in a function. And second, with the data you retrieve from that query, you generate another query which does the actual work.

Comment: @uteist, yes I fixed the typo. Thanks

Comment: Thank you bove! I will give it a try.

Comment: @Marius, I was going through some things and I realised something. Check the update.

Answer (score 1):

```
IEnumerable<YourTypeHere> myIEnumerable = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<YourTypeHere>(sqlQueryHere);
```

OR

```
List<YourTypeHere> myList = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery<YourTypeHere>(sqlQueryHere).ToList();
```

Should do the trick